# How to do a Hoplon CLJS Server or AJAX Call

Tags: hoplon, cljs-ajax

I am using Hoplon to create a fairly simple site and an stuck on the AJAX part. In the past I have used Castra as the backend but since it is no longer maintained I have switched to a normal LuminusWeb backend. I am in need of making a call to the server in which I will the server and then wait for a response. I know how to do it on the server side but I can't seem to find any information about how to do it on the Hoplon Client side.

How can I send a request to the server using an  AJAX call?

I know how to do it in jQuery and assume, possibly wrongly, there is something similar to $.POST in Hoplon.

Cheers

Comment: I have decided to go with the HTTP Kit library and will be posting the steps to get it working.

Comment: I thought I could do it in CLJS but HTTP Kit seems to only be for Clojure, what is a good library for CLJS Requests.

Comment: I found and got working "cljs-http" so I will be writing an answer in detail tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this AJAX problem that I found is to use the library 'cljs-http' and then you can make an synchronous request using a call such as:

```
(http/post "http://localhost:8080/" {:with-credentials? false})
```

Then, on the [cljs-http GitHub README.md](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) it gives plenty of examples so you can then do asynchronous in Hoplon.